# Leaflet map not working in release configuration

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, leaflet, openstreetmap

In my iOS app written in react native I created map based on WebView and Leaflet. On debug mode everything works alright, but in release configuration map won't show.

I use tiles over https so it should working in release configuration.

Why it doesn't work? Is there lack of any property in plist file?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "map won't show"? How does it look, can you provide a screenshot? Is your device making any network requests?

Comment: There is empty area, none is rendered.

Comment: White or grey ?

Comment: Transparent color